# explanation of an expansion procedure of a kinetic distribution equation

Tags: statistics, taylor-expansion

reading a book about statistical mechanics (kerson huang chapter 3) I got a trouble understanding the following:
We have

$f(r+v\delta t, v+ F/m\delta t, t+\delta t)=f(r,v,t)+K\delta t$

and then''expanding the left-hand side to first order in $\delta t$'' we obtain:

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + v\cdot\nabla_r+F/m\cdot\nabla_v)f(r,v,t)=K$

Im totally lost, can someone explain me the expansion procedure in this step? and recommend a good book or chapter on expansion? thank you very much

Comment: It's just first order Taylor expansion; the operator there is $\frac{d}{dt}$ (the total derivative), which has a component from the change in $r$, the change in $v$, and one arising directly from the change in $t$. Any calculus textbook will cover this.

Comment: A more rigorous version can be found here https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/golse/M2/PolyKinetic.pdf